Theoretical equation to describe capacity fade

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/357842717_How_do_Depth_of_Discharge_C-rate_and_Calendar_Age_Affect_Capacity_Retention_Impedance_Growth_the_Electrodes_and_the_Electrolyte_in_Li-Ion_Cells
I am trying to find a theoretical equation to model the relationship between cell capacity and DOD.
From this paper it seems that they have used this Deshpande and Bernardi equation to try to model this by taking the collected data points and trying to fit them to this equation. This results in the values for the fitting constraints. This I would consider as an experimental equation and not a theoretical one as it depends on the data collected to get the equation.
I am wondering how one would find the theoretical equation for this relationship. Specifically, starting with some known parameters such as the Crate, DOD, initial capacity of the battery to derive an equation to describe the theoretical equation for what it should be.
However, since this model relies on these fitting constraints it depends on additional collected data points to create the equation and I can't simply substitute in the variables for numbers to get the theoretical equation.
How would I go about finding the theoretical equation? Getting an equation not dependent on fitting constraints? I desperately need some theoretical equation for my research so that I can compare the experimental equation(by fitting a line onto the data points) to some theoretical equation. However, all the papers I've come across have models that all depend on fitting constraints.

Any model is going to involve fitting. It is not possible to predict the behavior of untold trillions of electrochemical reactions over long periods of time entirely from theory. You have to measure these things and feed them into a model.

Could we still make a model without fitting that doesn't need to be accurate? I'm not expecting it to predict all these reactions, I just need some model even if it is not entirely describing all the processes involved.

Yes, you could for example make a model that assumes that the battery does not wear out or that it wears out at some constant rate. That would be both inaccurate and not involved fitting to actual battery parameters.  Maybe it would be better to talk to your advisor though.

okay thank you for your input
